# OpenID Directed Identity/Identifier Selection in PHP

Tags: php, openid, directed-identity

I'm trying to implement an OpenID server in PHP that supports identifier selection (some call this directed identity, which is actually a more specific case of identifier selection).  That is, a user can enter a generic URI as their OpenID identifier, log in, and choose what identifier to return to the OpenID consumer.

For example, if a user enters **mysite.com** as their indentifier, after they log in they would be prompted to return one of two identifiers to the OpenID consumer (perhaps **mysite.com/myusername** or **mysite.com/anon-ad83f38c98b98**).

The advantage of this system is that you have the option to either use a single identifier among many sites, or use unique identifiers for individual sites.

Anyway—I haven't been able to find a good tutorial on how to implement this portion of the OpenID spec in PHP.  In fact, most searches led me to unanswered questions on forums or even on stack overflow.  Does anyone know of a PHP library that can handle identifier selection or directed identity?  If so, are there any tutorials out there explaining how to set it up?  I've been playing with a few libraries that don't mention it one way or the other, but I haven't been able to get it working yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is useless.  Have you had a look at the Janrain libraries?  They have a consumer which I have successfully implemented and also server code which I presume is implementable.  Have a look at the Yadis\XRIRes and Yadis\XRI files, you may have to reverse engineer their code - that's what I had to do to figure out the consumer.  I'm currently looking into implementing a server but can't find anything worthwhile yet.

http://openidenabled.com/files/php-openid/docs/2.1.3/OpenID/Auth_Yadis_Yadis.html

Comment: I have looked at the Janrain libraries, but the documentation is worthless and I'd rather not reverse engineer the code if at all possible.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to go digging in the Yadis code for a server implementation, unless you're wondering what Type URI constants the consumer is looking for.

Answer (score 0):

[php-openid](http://openidenabled.com/php-openid/) v2 is certainly capable.  And really, how you interact with the library changes rather little when you add identifier selection.  When you get your `Auth_OpenID_ChecKIDRequest`, you can check its `idSelect` method to see if it's a case for identifier selection.  Then pass the selected identity to `Auth_OpenID_ChecKIDRequest.answer()`.

The only other bit is to make sure that you advertise what the spec terms an "OP Identifier Element" on **mysite.com/**.  If you're serving XRDS pages for your user identifiers already, this works the same way, just with a different Type URL.  If you're not (you just have HTML-based discovery with `link` elements), you might want to look at myopenid's HTTP headers for an example.